# Code works after page load but not during

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on an app for internal company use and I'm publishing a list of users that qualify as "supervisor" (using [alanning:roles](http://atmosphere.js/alanning/roles).)

I'm also using [useraccounts:bootstrap](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/bootstrap) to collect additional information of each user during registration like who their supervisor is.

I have a function that returns the information I need but it only works when I run it in the browser console after the site has loaded.

If I build the array manually and return it, everything works as expected. The point, of course, is that this should be dynamic and grow as the userbase grows.

About all I know is that the code is not running in the context/order I think it is. I've tried various different things just to see what would happen like moving `routes.js` into `/lib` (from `/client`), moving the function definition into a different file, and more!

How can I correct this? I'm fairly new to Meteor so it's completely possible I'm making some other huge mistake and this difficulty I'm having is just a symptom of that. If so, **please let me know**!

`/server/publications.js`

```js
Meteor.publish('supervisor-list', function() {
  var criteria = {
    roles: {$in: ['supervisor']}
  };
  var options = {
    fields: {
      'profile.firstName': 1
      , 'profile.lastName': 1
    }
  };
  return Meteor.users.find(criteria, options);
});
```

`/client/routes.js`

```js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate:     'layout'
  , loadingTemplate:  'loading'
  , notFoundTemplate: '404'
  , waitOn:           function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('transactions')
      , Meteor.subscribe('supervisor-list')
    ];
  }
  , yieldTemplates:   {
    nav:      {to: 'nav'}
    , footer: {to: 'footer'}
  }
});
```

`/lib/1functions.js`

```js
getSupervisors = function () {
  var output = [];
  var supervisors = Meteor.users.find().fetch();

  for (var i = 0; i < supervisors.length; i++) {
    output.push({
      text:    supervisors[i].profile.firstName + ' ' + supervisors[i].profile.lastName
      , value: supervisors[i]._id
    });
  }

  //output = [
  //  {text: 'Person One', value: 'personone'}
  //  , {text: 'Person Two', value: 'persontwo'}
  //  , {text: 'Person Three', value: 'personthree'}
  //];

  return output;
};
```

`/lib/at_config.js`

```js
AccountsTemplates.addField({
  _id: 'supervisorEmail'
  , type: 'select'
  , select: getSupervisors()
  , required: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) (scroll down a bit to "File load order"). `/lib/at_config.js` is loaded before `/lib/functions.js`, so `getSupervisors` is not defined at that point yet.

Not sure how your code is structured in general, so I can not give any pointers as to how I would do this. The documentation is your friend here.

Comment: This was a dumb mistake on my part. I left off the 1 in the file name. The file is actually called `1functions.js` because of this load order issue.

Comment: Would it be a bad idea to put the function's output into a session variable when isServer and then retrieve it at isClient? ...OK that doesn't work because it's client only.